# "Стирающий" position: fixed блок HTML

Tags: html, css

Привет всем. Возникла проблема с реализацией эффекта при верстке страницы. Эффект состоит в том, что сверху экрана находится линия на отступе, спозиционирована фиксированно (fixed), которая, фактически, является таким себе "ластиком". То бишь, на сайте есть блоки, в которых есть контент. Опускаясь вниз сайта, должен происходить эффект стирания этой линией *именно* контента. Например, есть желтый блок, в котором зеленый блок с текстом. При скролле вниз желтый блок, по сути, поднимается вверх, несмотря на линию, а зеленый "падает вниз" этого фиксированного div-а (над линией). Пример приложил. Там так же есть подобный эффект с картинкой. Но не могу понять, как сделать подобное, когда присутствует условная многослойность. То есть, я могу задать то же самое для блока .container, но тогда .block не стирается, тк он внутренний блок. Картинка одна, она просто поднимается за счёт z-index, а вот затереть блок контента, оставив внешний желтый блок не могу.

Заранее благодарю.

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
.main {
  background-color: #FF6600;
  padding: 200px 0px 0px;
}
.fix {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #FF6600;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
.container {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
.block {
  background-color: green;
}
.big_pic {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="fix">
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu
  sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut
    arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie.</p>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque
        ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus
        at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse
        facilisis ullamcorper molestie.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut arcu
  sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Nam facilisis elit eu neque sodales fringilla. Morbi laoreet, ex sit amet sagittis congue, risus lorem tempor eros, pulvinar
  semper sem nunc non erat. Phasellus posuere metus lacus, sit am et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.et sollicitudin purus
  pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl.
  <img class="big_pic" src="http://katyaburg.ru/sites/default/files/pictures/krasota_prirody/krasivye_cvety_rozy_kartinki_foto_05.jpg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent non est sit amet tellus blandit cursus at tincidunt ex. Etiam arcu ante, cursus sed lectus eu, vehicula maximus quam. Nam vel quam porta, pretium leo vel, tristique velit. Quisque ut
  arcu sit amet quam imperdiet rutrum. Ut volutpat pharetra felis, ac dictum urna blandit ac. Suspendisse facilisis ullamcorper molestie. Nam facilisis elit eu neque sodales fringilla. Morbi laoreet, ex sit amet sagittis congue, risus lorem tempor eros,
  pulvinar semper sem nunc non erat. Phasellus posuere metus lacus, sit am et sollicitudin purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl. et sollicitudin
  purus pulvinar et. Curabitur diam arcu, viverra a magna at, faucibus imperdiet eros. Quisque eros metus, posuere in bibendum eget, mattis eget nisl. Nullam dui libero, gravida id dui ac, pellentesque gravida justo. Quisque id dolor non nunc scelerisque
  varius a malesuada felis. Duis aliquam malesuada tortor, quis laoreet lacus vestibulum ut. Sed a vestibulum nunc, in maximus magna. Donec vel ante in nisi volutpat venenatis quis sit amet purus. Nunc eget posuere tortor. Donec in mi lectus. Mauris iaculis
  aliquet orci, at condimentum ligula bibendum et. Cras egestas metus a pellentesque malesuada. Etiam et imperdiet arcu, nec gravida massa. Sed maximus, lorem a dignissim faucibus, lorem neque laoreet elit, ut scelerisque augue ex et odio. Suspendisse
  ut pretium magna, sed elementum neque. Donec efficitur lectus vitae erat gravida fringilla et vel ante. Sed consectetur, odio vel venenatis mattis, nisl felis dapibus quam, eget ultrices augue nisi quis sapien.
</div>
```

Comment: Что за стирание? Я вижу только фиксированный блок

Comment: При скролле вниз фиксированный блок перекрывает весь контент, но, например, img нет. Задача в том, чтобы этот блок "зачищал" определенный блок, а именно - зелёный из примера.

Comment: Вам нужно, чтобы желтый блок оставался видимым под фиксированным блоком, и в тоже время чтобы зеленый блок скрывался?

Comment: Именно так и нужно

Comment: Не сделать на css. Только если вы скриптами вынесете зеленый блок из под желтого. При этом зададите скриптом ему абсолютное позициониривание и нужные координаты.

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду зеленый блок сделать внутри желтого лишь визуально, я правильно понимаю? Задать ему абсолютное позиционирование, привязывая к окну просто, но разместить поверх желтого блока, так? Если да, то почему именно скриптом это делать?

Comment: Именно так. Скриптом за тем, чтобы можно было верстать как обычно. И чтобы не пришлось вручную записывать абсолютные значения. Просто считываете данные с блока и на его место кладете пустой заменитель, чтобы визуально ничего не прыгало

Comment: Не понял по поводу данных с блока и пустого заменителя. Если можно, то более подробно, пожалуйста. И еще один вопрос к вам. А что по поводу адаптива? Абсолютное позиционирование в любом случае скажется на этом, разве нет?